# Vue component set the data when mounted

Tags: javascript, datepicker, vuejs2, vue-component

I want set temporary data to vue component when it was mounted.and use it when need.in below code i created date picker and stored that object in **vue.obj** And want to use it when the show changed to true.but it doesn't worked.
any help please.

```
Vue.component('date-picker', {
template: "<input type='text' value='obj' class='form-control' placeholder='select date of birth' v-validate=\"'required'\" model='date'>",
props: ['date','show','obj'],
mounted: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.obj = $(this.$el).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(date) {
            self.$emit('update-date', date);
            $(self.$refs.datepicker).trigger('change');
        },
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        yearRange: '1900:' + new Date().getFullYear(),
        maxDate: new Date()
    });
},
watch:{
    show:function(newShow,oldShow){
        console.log(this);
        if(newShow && this.obj){
            this.obj.datepicker("show");
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: It works for me here https://codesandbox.io/s/lp5y5017yl
You shouldn't modify a props directly, however. "show" should be under data.

Comment: I didn't anything relevant to this question at your link